# InstaPy - Python - how to give a specific insta account 500 followers

Tags: python

I have a Ubuntu server and i installed / setup InstaPy on it:
https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy

Everything works fine on the server.
But how can i give a specific insta account +500 followers?

I don't have the password of the account and the account is open for public.

I can execute `quickstart.py` with `python quickstart.py`

I tried this but how can i give up a specific account without password to give that account 500 followers?

```
from instapy import InstaPy

insta_username = 'SpecificAccountName'
insta_password = ''

# if you want to run this script on a server, 
# simply add nogui=True to the InstaPy() constructor
session = InstaPy(username=insta_username, password=insta_password,nogui=True)
session.login()

# set up all the settings
session.set_upper_follower_count(limit=500)

# do the actual liking
session.like_by_tags(['natgeo', 'world'], amount=100)

# end the bot session
session.end()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply give an account 500 followers, that is not how InstaPy works.
The idea is to interact with other users content and get interaction back.

You also need the username and password of the account to be used, I'm sorry.

You might need to try one of the "Buy Instagram xyz" services.

Thank you